# WordPress - get_post_meta () returns false

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I want to display custom fields one by one.

I put this code

```
<p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'autore', true);?></p>
```

But returns false

Instead, If I use the_meta() displays all custom fields in a list.

Can you help me?

Comment: When you call `the_meta` is the case sensitivity of `autore` exactly the same? And when using `the_meta` are you seeing the expect value along with the meta key for that post?

Comment: With the_meta() it gives me the keys with a : at the end but i haven't added any in the custom field. I checked also the database and in the table is 'autore'

Comment: Yes with the_meta() i see the right value

Comment: can you try changing `'autore'` to `''` to see what you get with a `var_dump()`? I'm  not able to reproduce the problem under my wordpress

Comment: Are you sure that `$post` is defined in the scope this is running in, and is it the post object you expect it to be? `print $post->ID`, just to make sure, or just use `get_the_ID()` instead.

Comment: I found it. it was a very silly error. I changed ' with " in the second parameter : "autor" instead 'autor'.

Answer (score 1):

using $post->ID you have to make post global just add **global $post** to top and first of all test post id is return or not